# NullPointerException in array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, nullpointerexception

I keep getting a NullPointerException at (see below). Everything works fine in C#, but in android it breaks?

arrDBNumbers is full and code is supposed to run through and count the amount of #1, #2, #3 and so on to #49 adding 1 to arrFreq[i][1] to fill arrFreq with the total count of the numbers.

It runs through the if statement till k hits 6 where arrDBNumbers[0][6] is 1, then jumps inside if statement and then breaks? I'm not sure whats going on here any advice 
thanks in advance T

```
Integer[][] arrDBNumbers = new Integer[100][8];
Integer[][] arrFreq = new Integer[49][2];


for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 49; j++){
        for (int k = 1; k < 7; k++){
            if (arrDBNumbers[j][k] == (i + 1)){
                arrFreq[i][1]++;     //  < here is where I get Exception?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `i` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: While the question's been answered.. I think that's also susceptible to an IOBE.. k > 2.. also `i+1` if `i` is 48..?

Comment: Why do you use `Integer`s rather than `int`s?

Comment: It is a java question not android. It is better to change the title

Comment: No line number for nullpointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because just writing

```
Integer[][] arrFreq = new Integer[49][2];
```

*means you have initialized the array with all `null` elements because it is an array of `Integer` Objects and Object's default value will be null reference.*
Hence,

```
arrFreq[i][1]++;  // trying null++;
```

gives `NullPointerException`.

This wouldn't have been the case if you had used an *array of primitives, which will default to an array of `0`s.*

```
int[][] arrFreq = new int[49][2];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply, so Integer[][] arrFreq; and leave it at that yea.

Comment: *not sure why that is but it works* : Please check Java tutorials to know what are the default values of primitives and references.

Answer (score 0):

Integer is a container for int, in your case you have lots of null objects. if you use int instead it will work as you expect.